# How to set external property for ehcache

Tags: configuration, ehcache

I have an issue. The project is based on Maven. I have a property file, in which I have some variables. I want to call a variable from inside ehcache.xml file. I tried using `${name_of_variable}`, but it did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried this myself but this is what I would do:

use [maven properties plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to set the properties in your file as system properties.
after they are set as system properties you should be able to [reference](http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/2895.page) them in ehcache.xml using ${}